# How can I get data from MongoDb with starting and ending date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, dataframe, initialization

I am trying to pull data from MongoDb in pandas data frame but stuck here.

This is my code:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "./main/common")
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import logging
from db_handler import DBhandler


starttime = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7) 
endtime = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)

from_date = starttime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
yesterday = endtime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

class BmsLog:
    @classmethod
    def list(cls, my_num: int, yyMm: str, dd: str):
        dBHandler = DBhandler()
        dbName = 'bms'
        collName = 'bmsLog_'

        dateAt = yyMm + dd

        bmsLogs = dBHandler.find(
            condition={'my_)number': my_num, 'dateAt': dateAt},
            dbName=f'{dbName}',
            collName=f'{collName}{yyMm}',
        )
        print(bmsLogs)
        logging.info(f'List bms Logs. my_number: {my_number}, yyMm: {yyMm}, dd: {dd}, length: {len(bmsLogs)}')
        
        return bmsLogs
```

I connect my code with DBhandler.
This code gives me all data from branch of bms db. But only for a given date.
I want to get data from starting to ending data (desirable date).
How can i add such function?

Can I get some help?

I would like to include staring date = ....., and ending date = ..... with a my_number.
There are many my_number queries in DB but I want to get for specific number with specific data in Dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use [pymongo](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead which is the recommended library to work with MongoDB. Then you can use the standard MongoDB calls to get the required data based on the date range with:

```
collection = MongoClient(<your credentials>).get_database('bms').get_collection('bmsLog_')
collection.find({'my_number': my_num, 'dateAt': {'$gte': startDate,'$lte': endDate}})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I would like to ask you one question. If I want to connect my DB connector class instead of mongoClient, How can I use it? Thank you.

Comment: I could not find a library db_handler so I assume its a module of your project? I think you can simply put the Mongo query {'my_number': my_num, 'dateAt': {'$gte': startDate,'$lte': endDate}} as the "condition" paramter.

Comment: Oh sorry, because of few personal information I couldn't upload that file. Basically it has client link and it handles DB and information. Let me serach more, I will try to  connect that library .